# How to prove that inequality for every $f\in C^\infty_0(\Bbb{R})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, differential-operators

Prove that there is  a constant $c>0$ such that : $$
 \int^\infty_0 \left|\partial^2_r  f+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r f+r^2f\right|^2 rdr\ge c  \int_{\Bbb{R^+}}|f(r)|^2 rdr$$

for every $f\in C^\infty_0(\Bbb{R})$.

Thank you for any suggestion whatsoever.

Comment: Is $R^+=(0,\infty)$? If so, why use different notation on either side of the inequality?

Comment: The inequality should be $\geq$ since we have equality when $f \equiv 0.$

Comment: It's probably a good start to rewrite $\partial^2_r  f+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r f$ as $r^{-2}(r \partial_r)^2 f.$

Comment: Ok, I put $>=$ instead $>$.

Comment: $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^+)$ are different; which do you want?

Comment: And does $C^\infty_0$ mean "compact support" or just vanishing at the boundary (or infinity) for you?

Comment: It might also be useful to give more context. The first two terms on the left hand side are the 2D Laplacian in polar coordinates for a radial function, and the $rdr$ on both sides suggests this is a 2D integral of a radial function...

Comment: I m sorry I want to write  $ f\in C^\infty_{0}(\Bbb{R}^+)$ or $ f\in C^\infty_{0}(\Bbb{R})$ and $ C^\infty_{0}(\Omega)$ means "compact support". In fact I want to show for a  radial function with a support compact, we have the followin inequality in dimension $ n=2$,  $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}|\Delta(f(x,y))|^2dxdy>= c \int_{\Bbb{R}^2}|f(x,y)|^2dxdy$ .

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense. But the left hand side is not correct then; where does the $r^2f$ come from? The Laplacian is just the first two terms. And you really want $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is even. If you say $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^+)$, then $f$ must vanish near zero as well, which is more than you are asking I think.

Comment: you are right, i have $(\Delta +x^2+y^2)$ and $f\in C^\infty_0(\Bbb{R})$. As you saying if we use the polar coordinates one can chose $f\in C^\infty_0(\Bbb{R}^+)$. Thanks

Comment: Please write down exactly what estimate you want to prove as an integral in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then maybe I can help.

Comment: Ok, i want to show that,  $\exists c>0:\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}|(\Delta+x^2+y^2)(f(x,y))|^2dxdy>= c \int_{\Bbb{R}^2}|f(x,y)|^2dxdy$ for every radial function $f$ with a support compact on $\Bbb{R}^2$ .